# AndEngine rotate all connected bodies

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

I have created below hexagon structure in `Andengine` with `Box2D` physics engine. I want to rotate whole structure with respect to center when other ball collides with the structure using physics.

find reference image here : [reference question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/92148/andengine-rotate-all-connected-bodies)

I tried `weld joint` and `revolute joint` with the bodies but it is not performing proper motion as required. All bodies are attached with `weld joint` and vertices have `revolute joint` with center body which is static like,

```
RevoluteJointDef revoluteJointDef1 = new RevoluteJointDef();
revoluteJointDef1.initialize(centerB, movingBody[i], centerB.getWorldCenter());
revoluteJointDef1.enableMotor = true;
revoluteJointDef1.motorSpeed = 0;
revoluteJointDef1.maxMotorTorque = 1f;
this.mPhysicsWorld.createJoint(revoluteJointDef1);
```

Is there any other way to perform smooth rotation of whole structure?
Thanks.

Comment: Is there any way if i can add a big circle disc body and attach balls on top of it which will rotate all bodies?

Comment: Does your structure need to be made from multiple bodies, or could it be multiple fixtures on a single body?

Comment: I was constructing it with multiple bodies but if it is possible to detect individual fixtures on single body than it is fine.

Comment: The BeginContact callback gives you a b2Contact, from which you can get the two fixtures that began contacting. http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/collision-callbacks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh! i got solution by myself... I did the same thing as i mentioned in first comment my question where I attached balls on a big circle body like,

```
Body circleBody ... ;// having large radius
//for all balls arranged in hexagon structure
foreach BallBody b
{
WeldJointDef def = new WeldJointDef();
def.initialize(b, circleBody, b.getWorldCenter());
mPhysicsWorld.createJoint(def);
}
```

and got the rotation by having revolute joint of circleBody with center. Thanks who put their efforts.